# background: none - how to enable with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this style in my project:

```
<span id="here" style="background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #E5ECF9">test</span>
```

with no background-color etc.

How can I enable the background with jQuery?

```
$("#here").css ????
```

EDIT:

$('#here').css('backgroundColor', '#336699');
doesnt working. In project is jquery for this and i cant overwrite this :(

Comment: It does in fact work. If not, then probably your jQuery code isn't running at all, or running at the wrong time.  You should post more of your code.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by enabling the background ?

```
$("#here").css('background-color', 'red');
```

Comment: @Timothy probably you didnt set and width/height of the span so you cant see the color.

Comment: @Pheonix You can't set the width and height of a span; it sizes itself to its content automatically.

Comment: I think you need either the CSS formatting 'background-color' or the DOM formatting 'backgroundColor'.  (I think it's case-sensitive lower camel case, so the upper case C matters... but I could be mistaken).

Comment: @TimothyGrees Mr Lister is right, but the example works with some text inside the Span... http://jsfiddle.net/SZ6PM/3/

Comment: I created a jsFiddle for your solution and it works great: http://jsfiddle.net/bCFtH/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#here").css("background-color", "red");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7PT9D/

Comment: and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Pointy/7PT9D/1/) is the same fiddle using a `<span>` and it does work.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>The value "none" for "background" doesn't make sense.</strike> (*edit* thanks BoltClock) You can set the individual components of the background ("backgroundColor", "backgroundImage", "backgroundPosition", etc) via jQuery.

Probably you want:

```
$('#here').css('backgroundColor', 'transparent');
```

to make it be "none" and:

```
$('#here').css('backgroundColor', '#336699');
```

to make it be some color.

Comment: `none` is a value for `background-image`, so it's fine to use with the shorthand property.

Comment: @BoltClock yes that's true; is it understood thusly?  Hmm well I guess it's the only thing in the set of properties that *can* be "none" so that (sort-of) makes sense.

Comment: updated my question: <span id="here" style="background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #E5ECF9">test</span>

Comment: Yes, css `background: none` is perfectly valid. However, it seems you can't set shorthand css properties with jQuery, unless I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: @MrLister yes that's correct. I think it's basically because the browsers don't (all) do that, but I could be wrong.

Comment: I don't know any browser that doesn't recognise the shorthand `background` property, although some seem to have problems if you use both `background` and any of the individual `background-` properties in the same style rule.

Comment: @MrLister well I'm sure you're right; personally I try pretty hard not to update element styles directly so I don't have much recent experience.